# Cannot update path in timestamp value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Here is my problem, I'm trying to insert a bunch of data into elastic search and to vizualize it using kibana, however I got an issue with kibana timestamp recognition.
My time field is called "dateStart", and I tried to use it as a timestamp using the following command :

```
 curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test/type1/_mapping' -d'{ "type1" :{"_timestamp":{"enabled":true, "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","path":"dateStart"}}}'
```

But this command give me the following error message :

```
{"error":"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[Cannot update path in _timestamp value. Value is null path in merged mapping is missing]}]","status":400}
```

I'm not sure to understand what I do with this command, but what I would like to do is telling to elastic search and kibana to use my "dateStart" field as a timestamp.

Here is a sample of my insert file (I use bulk insert) :

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1"} }
{ "dateStart" : "15-03-31 06:00:00", "score":0.9920092243874442}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2"} }
{ "dateStart" : "15-03-23 06:00:00", "score":0.0}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3"} }
{ "dateStart" : "15-03-29 12:00:00", "score":0.0}
```

Comment: Have you tried to include the full mapping in your first query?

Comment: Also I see that your date format is wrong, you're specifying 4-digit years `yyyy`, while in fact in your bulk queries the dates use 2-digit years.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my issue by including a date mapping on my dateStart field